# Java: How do I find the Process ID of another program?

Tags: java, eclipse, process, pid

I'm wondering how I find the Process ID of another program. (non-java)

When I started programming my program I thought that the process of a .exe stayed the same, but when my program failed I rechecked and realized it changed!

I have tried many different ways from across the internet but none of them had a non-java program as the target.

Here is my current code:

```
try {
                        System.out.println("DefaultButton Pressed");
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID "+processID);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Failed to kill the process");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This code trys to kill the process when I press a button

I had code that tried to grab the PID but it failed as well

I have tried this to grab the PID, but it grabs my process's ID (duh). I have been attempting to change the code to be a different non java program but the code still doesn't work.

```
String processID= ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
System.out.println("Process ID for this app = " + processID);
```

again this is code to grab their own code.

I can not adjust it to work.

Can I even get a PID of another non java process?

**EDIT 1**
Here is my new code

```
Process processIdRaw;
            try{
                processIdRaw = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /m | find \"<processname>" ");
                System.out.println("Aquired PID");

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int processID = Integer.parseInt(processIdRaw);
            System.out.println("PID:"+processID);
```

This code is before my other code. The other code comes after this above code.

I think the type `Process` doesn't work with `int processID = Integer.parseInt(processIdRaw);`

I have added the `.parseInt` because I though it would find the number from the output.

Errors out before because of the type `Process`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to make the PID work but!

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe")
```

works!

```
try {
                        System.out.println("DefaultButton Pressed");
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Failed to kill the process");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

To find the process name

1: Run the program you want to kill

2: Run CMD

3: Run the command tasklist

4: Grab the process name